# android visiblity - reserve space of image view

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, android-linearlayout

I want android:visibility to resolve in xml layout based on a boolean returned.
 like android:visibility="card.isPrimary() ? 1 : 0".

Android documentation says visible, invisible and gone are ints 0,1,2. My understanding is true/1 would resolve to invisible and false/0 to visible.

Layout:

```
 <LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:visibility="@{ creditCard.isPrimary()}"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src= "@drawable/creditcard" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Then set the visibility to INVISIBLE rather than GONE.

Comment: can I do it layout itself ? android:visibility = " @{ creditcard.isprimary ? 'visible' : 'invisible" }"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then, isPrimary() should return the corresponding visibility value

```
@Visibility int isPrimary() {
    return primary ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE;
}
```